# Toggle between CSS styling that's given by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle between two CSS styling that is given by jQuery.

Basically this is my code:

```
$('#reveal').click(function() {
    window.scrollTo( 0, 1 );

    $('.boxs').slideToggle(1000, function() {
        $('#bubs').toggle(function () {
            $('#bubs').animate({"position":"relative","margin-top":"320px"}, 1000);
        }, function () {
            $('#bubs').animate({"position":"fixed","top":"0"}, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

so I need to toggle between `

```
$('#bubs').animate({"position":"relative","margin-top":"320px"}, 1000);
```

and

```
$('#bubs').animate({"position":"fixed","top":"0"}, 1000);
```

but what I am doing is wrong thus my code doesn't function at all and it doesn't toggle.

Could someone please let me know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Add your HTML related to the script

Comment: The jQuery `.toggle` event was [**deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9**](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). If you search the web for toggleClick you should find a jQuery plugin that does what `.toggle` event used to do.

Comment: @PeterKA but confusingly there still is the [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) effect... Anyway, toggle can be mimiced really easily. Using an oldschool if/else ;)

Comment: Well, @giorgio, I think the confusion is part of the reason it was removed. However, if you look at the method signatures the deprecated one is the only one that accepted only methods as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .toggle event was deprecated in [1.8 and removed in 1.9](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Even though I would not recommend it, the only way your code would work is if you use jQuery 1.8 and below.

You can use [**`toggleClick()` jQuery plugin**](https://github.com/maniator/jQuery-toggleClick) with the latest version of jQuery. Take a look at an example usage [**here**](https://github.com/JakeCigar/toggleClick/blob/master/demo.html). With the plugin, your code would become:

```
    $('#bubs').toggleClick(function () {
        $(this).animate({"position":"relative","margin-top":"320px"}, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({"position":"fixed","top":"0"}, 1000);
    });
```